# How can robust regression be used with penalty functions for sparse solutions?

Tags: regression, regularization, robust

I don't seem to see robust regression used with penalty functions for variable selection, either L1 or Huber can't use mathematica's Fit at the same time

Comment: Are you asking how robust regression can be combined with regularization, or how to implement it in Mathematica? Only the former is on-topic here, and you might be interested in [robust ridge regression](http://asq.org/qic/display-item/index.html?item=33248). Alternatively, you could simply opt for $\ell_1$-penalized regression, which penalizes for the absolute value of coefficients and is therefore more robust to outliers than ridge regression.

Comment: @FransRodenburg but ridge regression cannot be used for variable selection.I want to be able to select variables and be robust enough

Comment: $\ell_1$-penalization is LASSO, not ridge.

Comment: @FransRodenburg You mean LASSO is a kind of robust regression?

Comment: @FransRodenburg But that paper didn't use the sparse penalty function.This is where I get confused